# How can I suppress ruff linting on a block of code

Tags: python, lint, ruff

I would like to disable/suppress the ruff linter (or certain linting rules) on a block of code. I know that I can do this for single lines (by using `# noqa: <rule_code>` at the end of the line) or for entire files/folder (`#ruff: noqa <rule_code>` at the top of the file).

However, I would like to disable the linter ruff on one function or on a multi-line block of code, but not an entire file. Is there a way to do this, without adding `noqa` to the end of each line?

Answer (score 2):

Not currently possible (as of 29 Jan 2024). See [here](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/3711) for updates on the issue

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify this in your question, but if this is about `ruff format`, and you want to generally disable it for a block of code, you can actually do this using the fmt comment:

```
# fmt: off

def my_unformatted_function():
   do_something()

# fmt: on
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was talking about linting, though. I will update my question to clarify that.